# R cannot be resolved to a variable - Deleted Appcompat_v7

Tags: android, eclipse, import, android-resources, android-appcompat

Today I deleted by mistake appcompat_v7 and few of my apps got this error:

```
R cannot be resolved to a variable
```

I tried with importing my package name, but eclipse changes it by default to `import android.R;`
Is there anything I can do? I did clean project several times it didn't work.

Comment: There is some error in your project, when you fix it, you will have R class again

Comment: The error `R cannot be resolved to a variable` appears in all activities, even in values folders. And I am asking how to fix that _bug_ if anyone has any idea. The problem is quiet unique since this new appcompat_v7 folders create automatically

Comment: Have you readded appcompat dependency in the project properties?

Comment: No. Wish I did tho. It was an act of ignorance I deleted it without thinking. But then I read some topics about that, and my min Api was 8 and targeted API 15 so I thought its not important for me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try readding the appcompat_v7 to the project. It is in `/path-to-sdk/extras/android/support/v7/appcompat`.
Or you can set the **minimum sdk** attribute in the Manifest.xml to 14.

Comment: You are a saver! I added library again and it worked. It doesn't have to be jar in sdk folder, I just added appcompat_v7 that was automatically created today by other app and it worked. Errors are gone-App is working like before nothing has changed. Thanks you so much!